# How can I tell if there’s enough water in a hot water boiler system that doesn’t have a pressure gauge

Tags: boiler, radiator, cast-iron

It has an automatic water filling system with a Watts pressure valve SB1156F but the third floor radiator was empty.

I’ve held the purge lever on the pressure valve open to fill the third floor cast iron radiator but don’t want to overfill the system. The elevation difference between the boiler and the third floor radiator is about 36 feet.

Thank you

Comment: you can not overfill, it will only take what it can

Comment: A particularly asinine comment from @asinine today. Have them come clean up when your relief valve spews water all over the place if you follow it.

Comment: At least ruskies isn't knowitall anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IRC M2002.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018P7/chapter-20-boilers-and-water-heaters) requires **every** hot water boiler to have a temperature gauge and a pressure gauge, or a combination pressure and temperature gauge. I would expect the same of any different applicable code, if IRC is not the baseline code for your local area having jurisdiction.

Not only is it as idiotic as I instantly thought to have a boiler without a gauge, yes, it's actually a code violation. So, get that fixed, and you'll have a gauge.

36 feet of water is 15.6 PSI

Note that needing to add water to a closed loop boiler system (after the initial fill and the air-purge after the initial fill) indicates that there is a leak in the "not as closed as it should be" loop, and it's best to find and fix those. The water is going somewhere, and the new water being added voids the assumption that the loop is free of oxygen (once the initial air purge and some rusting of the iron parts has completed) so the iron parts will continue to rust more as new water comes in with new oxygen. That does not happen in a system where the loop is properly closed and the oxygen is exhausted.

Comment: Thank you. I found it after opening up the cover on the side of the boiler. The gauge shows 15 lbs pressure or about 35 feet H2O. 

The radiator has not provided heat for the past couple of years, it’s in the attic, so not a big deal. It could just have not been filled properly when we had work done before that. Should I set the pressure to slightly higher than 15.6 psi?

Comment: Check your relief valve setting (typically 30 PSI, but might be 25) - Assuming it's 30, I'd head for 20 PSI and feel pretty safe about not overshooting unless the expansion tank is bad (and if it is, you need a new one.) So long as you don't get so high that the relief valve triggers when things are hot, more pressure in the system reduces the chance of cavitation in your pump (with cavitation in your pump being a bad thing you can look up.)